# Styled component (React+ts): Have a custom behaviour for a child with customized props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

My parent component can have multiple panels. One is the first of the list, and I would like him to have a smaller margin-top. How can I do that ?

```
export const StandardPanel = styled.div<{ first?: boolean }>`
  margin-top: 45px;
`
```

From a parent component in another file

```
// Not working because first would refer to a props of Root component
const Root = styled.div`
  ${StandardPanel} {
    margin-top: ${props => (props.first ? '10px' : '45px')};
  }
`
```

Comment: Maybe better use css selectors (first-child) for this task?

Comment: and can you also show the jsx code of `<styled.Root>` and StandardPanels inside